# How to suppress XML tag for list property

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Is it possible to avoid list property tags when serializing?

```
//[Serializable()] - removed, unnecessary
public class Foo
{
    protected List<FooBar> fooBars = new List<FooBar>();
    public virtual List<FooBar> FooBars
    {
        get { return fooBars; }
        set { fooBars = value; }
    }
}

// [Serializable()] - removed, unnecessary
public class FooBar
{
    public int MyProperty
    { get; set; }
}
```

Serializing Foo gives (except the comment):

```
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FooBars>    <!-- Unwanted tag -->
    <FooBar>
      <MyProperty>7</MyProperty> 
    </FooBar>
    <FooBar>
      <MyProperty>9</MyProperty> 
    </FooBar>
  </FooBars>
</Foo>
```

Wanted output:

```
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FooBar>
    <MyProperty>7</MyProperty> 
  </FooBar>
  <FooBar>
    <MyProperty>9</MyProperty> 
  </FooBar>
```

Comment: [Serializable] has nothing to do with XML Serialization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("FooBar")]
public virtual List<FooBar> FooBars 
{ 
    get { return fooBars; } 
    set { fooBars = value; }
}
```

Results in

```
<FooMain xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http:/
/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FooBar>
    <MyProperty>7</MyProperty>
  </FooBar>
  <FooBar>
    <MyProperty>76</MyProperty>
  </FooBar>
  <FooBar>
    <MyProperty>67</MyProperty>
  </FooBar>
</FooMain>
```