# C# xml inline array deserialization

Tags: c#, xml

What is the easiest way to deserialize xml like this:

```
<root>
    <item id="1"/>
    <item id="2"/>
    <item id="3"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Deserialize to what form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> items = XDocument.Parse("the xml")
                         .Descendants("item")
                         .Select(item => item.Attribute("id").Value).ToList();
```

Use XDocument!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it is possible - the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314343/165656) shows how. Just define the property as array but annotate with `XmlElement`

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get ;set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public Item[] Items { get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to parse the xml.

Deserializing it would require a scheme that is supported by XmlSerializer, use XDocument to parse it.

Here is an example of serialization:

**Define the class**

```
public class item
{
    [XmlAttribute("item")]
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

**Serialize it**

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(item[]));
xs.Serialize(File.Open(@"c:\Users\roman\Desktop\ser.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate), new item[] { new item { id = "1" }, new item { id = "1" }, new item { id = "1" } });
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfItem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <item item="1" />
  <item item="1" />
  <item item="1" />
</ArrayOfItem>
```

As you can see it uses a special xml schema, making your xml unparseable, meaning you will either have to parse your xml manually, by using XDocument or XmlDocument, or serialize your data using XmlSerializer first, then deserialize it.